# Log4j Logger for Struts 2 Exception Interceptor

Tags: java, struts2, log4j

Which logger do I list in my log4j.xml to trap unhandled struts 2 exceptions?

I have the following code declared in my struts.xml:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
   <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
      <interceptor-ref name="timer"/> 
  <interceptor-ref name="logger"/> 
      <interceptor-ref name="exception">
            <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
            <param name="logCategory">error.unhandled</param>
            <param name="logLevel">WARN</param>
      </interceptor-ref>
   </interceptor-stack>
</package>
```

In my log4j.xml file, I have the following logger declared:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p [%c] - %C{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="error.unhandled">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>
```

However, when Struts throws an exception, it is not properly logged by log4j. I know that my log4j.xml is being parsed correctly since I can manually create a java class with a logger called "error.unhandled" and write ERROR level messages directly to it. A colleague also suggested that I should try trapping the log4j.logger.error.unhandled logger but that did not work either.

Which logger does Struts 2 use for the exception interceptor?

Comment: Can you manually log something at WARN level and have it show up in the log?

Comment: What type of container are you deploying to? (i.e. Tomcat, JBoss, WebSphere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using log level WARN in your interceptor definition. Change that to ERROR and you'll see the log messages, or alternatively reduce the logger level to WARN, INFO or DEBUG in the log4j.xml file.

In other words, the interceptor sends out a message at WARN level, the console appender receives that message but *chooses* not to print it because it is configured to print only messages at ERROR level.

Comment: I lowered the error level all the way down to DEBUG, but it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: struts uses commons logging, so perhaps your problem lies elsewhere. Are commons-logging and log4j both configured properly?

Comment: Where would I configure commons-logging at? I've only configured log4j.xml

Comment: commons-logging doesn't have configuration files, it is designed to "pass through" the logging requests to another logging library, such as log4j. If I recall correctly, you need to have commons-logging-api.jar and commons-logging.jar in your webapp lib library, but that's a completely different topic ... good luck :)

Comment: JCL has the commons-logging.properties file but its not needed in most circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is to provide parameters for exception interceptor in default interceptor stack. In example posted in question you are redefining default stack.

Solution is taken from official wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/exception-handling.html

To enable logging of the exceptions being handled by the Struts 2 framework you must specify some parameter values in struts.xml.

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
     <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
     <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
 </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="appDefaultStack" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logger in `log4.xml` has its threshold set to `ERROR`, so anything logged below that level will not be recorded. Your struts config is set to log at `WARN` level, which is below `ERROR`.

You should probably reduce the threshold in the `log4j.xml` `logger` to `WARN`, in order to get anything.

Comment: I lowered the error level all the way down to DEBUG, but it didn't help. Any other ideas?